# Программа не работает в фоновом режиме

Tags: python, многопоточность, pyqt, сигналы-слоты, qthread

При изменении языка раскладки необходимо переключать цвет, но этого не происходит, если вы свернете компилятор / выбираете другое окно, на консоли отображается, что номер языка не меняется, если выбрать окно с программой, цвет меняется. использовали *win32api* и *PyQt5*.

```
class ColorWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)

        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt.Tool)

        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 100, 100)
        
        self.layout = "unknown"

    def paintEvent(self, event):

        painter = QPainter(self)
       
        if self.layout == "ru":
            painter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt.red))
        
        elif self.layout == "en":
            painter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt.green))
        
        else:
            painter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt.gray))
       
        painter.drawEllipse(0, 0, 100, 100)


class ColorThread(QThread):
    def __init__(self, widget):
        super().__init__()
        self.widget = widget
    def run(self):
        while True:
           
            self.widget.update()
           
            self.widget.layout = get_layout()
            
            self.sleep(1)


def get_layout():
   
    id = win32api.GetKeyboardLayout()
    print(id)
    if id == 68748313:
        return "ru"
    elif id == 67699721:
        return "en"
    else:
        return "unknown"
app = QApplication([])
widget = ColorWidget()
thread = ColorThread(widget)
thread.start()
widget.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 2):

Я проверил ваше приложение, но не использую строку

```
id = win32api.GetKeyboardLayout()
```

которую заменил на строку

```
id = random.choice([68748313, 67699721, 12345678])
```

и я конечно был удивлен, что ваше приложение у меня работало.
А удивлен потому что не рекомендуется взаимодействовать
с виджетами в дополнительном потоке, так как это небезопасно. 
Для этого существует механизм сигналов и слотов.

Я подправил ваше приложение, проверьте его работу.
А затем строку, о  которой я писал выше замените на свою

```
id = win32api.GetKeyboardLayout()
```

и проверьте еще раз.

```
import sys
import win32api
import random
from random import choice
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


def get_layout():
   
#    id = win32api.GetKeyboardLayout()                # попробуйте и с этой строкой,
    id = random.choice([68748313, 67699721, 12345678])# а это строку закомментируете
    print(id)
    return id
    
    '''
    if id == 68748313:
        return "ru"
    elif id == 67699721:
        return "en"
    else:
        return "unknown"
    '''
 

class ColorThread(QThread):
    signalId = pyqtSignal(object)                         # !!! +++
    
    def __init__(self):                                   #, widget):
        super().__init__()
#        self.widget = widget

    def run(self):
        while True:
#            self.widget.update()                         # нет, это небезопасно
#            self.widget.layout = get_layout()
            id = get_layout()
            self.signalId.emit(id)                        # !!! +++
            self.msleep(1000)


class ColorWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        self.setWindowFlags(
            Qt.FramelessWindowHint 
            | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint 
# ???       | Qt.Tool
        )

#        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 100, 100)
        self.setGeometry(160, 300, 100, 100)
        
        self.id = None                                   # "unknown"
        
        self.thread = ColorThread()
        self.thread.signalId.connect(self.update_id)     # !!! +++    
        QTimer.singleShot(100, self.thread.start)   
        
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
       
#        if self.layout == "ru":
        if self.id == 68748313:
            painter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt.red))
        
#        elif self.layout == "en":
        elif self.id == 67699721:
            painter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt.green))
        
        else:
            painter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt.gray))
       
        painter.drawEllipse(0, 0, 100, 100)

    def update_id(self, id):                                  # !!! +++
        print(f'id = {id}') #  
        self.id = id                                          # !!! +++
        self.update()                                         # !!! +++
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    widget = ColorWidget()
#    thread = ColorThread(widget)
#    thread.start()
    widget.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**UPDATE**:

С использованием библиотеки **`ctypes`**:

```
import sys
#import win32api
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

from ctypes import WinDLL                                            # +++
user32 = WinDLL('user32', use_last_error=True)                       # +++

def get_layout():
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    foregroundWindow  = user32.GetForegroundWindow();
    foregroundProcess = user32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(int(foregroundWindow), 0)
    keyboardLayout    = user32.GetKeyboardLayout(int(foregroundProcess))
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    print(f'keyboardLayout = {keyboardLayout}')
    return keyboardLayout    
    
#    id = win32api.GetKeyboardLayout(0)         
#    return id
 

class ColorThread(QThread):
    signalId = pyqtSignal(object)                         # !!! +++
    
    def __init__(self):                                   #- , widget):
        super().__init__()
#        self.widget = widget

    def run(self):
        while True:
#            self.widget.update()                         # нет, это небезопасно
#            self.widget.layout = get_layout()
            id = get_layout()
            self.signalId.emit(id)                        # !!! +++
            self.msleep(1000)


class ColorWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        self.setWindowFlags(
            Qt.FramelessWindowHint 
            | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint 
# ???       | Qt.Tool
        )

#        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 100, 100)
        self.setGeometry(350, 300, 100, 100)
        
        self.id = None                                   # "unknown"
        
        self.thread = ColorThread()
        self.thread.signalId.connect(self.update_id)     # !!! +++    
        QTimer.singleShot(100, self.thread.start)   
        
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
       
#        if self.layout == "ru":
        if self.id == 68748313:
            painter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt.red))
        
#        elif self.layout == "en":
        elif self.id == 67699721:
            painter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt.green))
        
        else:
            painter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt.gray))
       
        painter.drawEllipse(0, 0, 100, 100)

    def update_id(self, id):                                  # !!! +++
        #print(f'id = {id}') #  
        self.id = id                                          # !!! +++
        self.update()                                         # !!! +++
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    widget = ColorWidget()
#    thread = ColorThread(widget)
#    thread.start()
    widget.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У меня, она, кстати, не работала вовсе.

Comment: Изначальная версия программы предложенная Данилом у меня не работала. Вашу не проверял

Comment: Ваша тоже не работает по какой-то причине. Windows 7. с win32api ничего не происходит, а с рандомом просто меняет цвет независимо от раскладки

Comment: @WTFisGoingOn значит надо искать проблему в строке `id = win32api.GetKeyboardLayout()`

Comment: @WTFisGoingOn а второй вариант можете проверить

Comment: Со вторым вариантом отлично работает)

Comment: @WTFisGoingOn спасибо за участие, я отметил ваши труды.

Comment: @ДанилЕлашкин что не так?